# Replace a feature class in a feature class list

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcpy

I'm using arcpy with arcgis 10.0. I try a script that erase successively all the feature class of a list depending on a reliability field value. Each time a feature class is erased by an other one, I want to replace the corresponding feature by the erased one. The problem is that I'm doing it wrong. Check the "HERE IS THE PROBLEM" comment in the code below :

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.workspace = r'Z:\Documents\SIG\tests\agregation_auto\erase.gdb'
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() 
outFolder = r"Z:\Documents\SIG\tests\agregation_auto"
count = 0 #help select the a feature class
cnt = 1 #help select the b feature class
tList = len(fcList) #Count the number of elements in the list
for count in range(tList - 1):
    for cnt in range(cnt,tList): 
        desca = arcpy.Describe(fcList[count])
        descb = arcpy.Describe(fcList[cnt])
        namea = desca.baseName # Get the name of the a feature to name the out_poly
        nameb = descb.baseName # Get the name of the b feature to name the out_poly
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, fcList[count]), "fca")
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, fcList[cnt]), "fcb")
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("fca","NEW_SELECTION")
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("fcb","INTERSECT","fca")

        if arcpy.Describe("fcb").FIDSet: #Check for selection
            rowa = arcpy.SearchCursor("fca")
            rowb = arcpy.SearchCursor("fcb")
            for row in rowa:
                fiabia = row.fiabilité #get the int value of reliability (all entities of a layer have the same)
            for rows in rowb:
                fiabib = rows.fiabilité
         if fiabia > fiabib: 
             out_poly = os.path.join(outFolder, nameb + "_er_" + namea + str(count) + "_" + str(cnt))
             tmpb = arcpy.Erase_analysis("fcb","fca", out_poly)
             fcList[cnt] = tmpb # I think HERE IS THE PROBLEM
          if fiabia < fiabib:
             out_poly = os.path.join(outFolder, namea + "_er_" + nameb + str(count) + "_" + str(cnt))
             tmpa = arcpy.Erase_analysis("fcb","fca", out_poly)
             fcList[count] = tmpa # I think HERE IS THE PROBLEM
```

Comment: just a guess from a quick look, but isn't it fcList[count]=out_poly ?

Comment: Fidset is just a list of selected features ids. Are you sure that your 1st IF working as expected?

Comment: Also select by attribute without query looks interesting. Is it clear_selection you are after. Deleting cursor at the end of the loop isn't bad idea either

Comment: @radouxju you're right, it must be out_poly but it don't change the problem. The replacement take into account a path, and not a feature class.

Comment: @FelixIP, select attribute without query leads to select all. And I'm sure of my first if, this is a technique with arcpy 10.0 to test the intersection (select by attribute, then select by location, if nothing is selected, no intersection, else do the job). The problem is not in this part of the code (tested and working). The real problem is that I don't know how to replace the feature class in the list by the updated one after the erase tool.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is delete your old feature class and then rename the result of your erase to the name of your old feature class.

Here's the code:

```
if fiabia > fiabib: 
    out_poly = os.path.join(outFolder, nameb + "_er_" + namea + str(count) + "_" + str(cnt))
    arcpy.Erase_analysis("fcb","fca", out_poly)
    arcpy.Delete_management (fcList[cnt])
    arcpy.Rename_management (out_poly,  fcList[cnt])
if fiabia < fiabib:
    out_poly = os.path.join(outFolder, namea + "_er_" + nameb + str(count) + "_" + str(cnt))
    arcpy.Erase_analysis("fcb","fca", out_poly)
    arcpy.Delete_management (fcList[count])
    arcpy.Rename_management (out_poly,  fcList[count])
```

You might have to fiddle with the pathing to get it in the right spot. But hopefully this gets you going in the right direction. You're deleting data, so make backups until you get your code right.

If you are instead just wanting to change the items in the list, radouxju is correct:

```
if fiabia > fiabib: 
    out_poly = os.path.join(outFolder, nameb + "_er_" + namea + str(count) + "_" + str(cnt))
    arcpy.Erase_analysis("fcb","fca", out_poly)
    fcList[cnt] = out_poly
if fiabia < fiabib:
    out_poly = os.path.join(outFolder, namea + "_er_" + nameb + str(count) + "_" + str(cnt))
    arcpy.Erase_analysis("fcb","fca", out_poly)
    fcList[count] = out_poly
```

Comment: a few weeks after stopping thinking to this problem, I come back ! In fact, I'm struggling hard to "fiddle" this pathing problem. I tried to directely overwrite wih fcList[count] = arcpy.Erase...but it put the out fc at the end of the list. Then I delete the fcList[0] and replace it by the last one, but it seems that the list of characters is independent from the real layer. The change in the list does not infer on the real fc. I don't know what try anymore, if somebody has some ideas, it would be much appreciated. Bye